# Calibration server not working on ARToolKit5 . Unable to fetch calibration file on Android device

Tags: android, artoolkit

When ever I run **ARToolKit5** android project , it takes hell lot of time to open up camera and I am getting this log -

```
E/libar: Error performing CURL operation: Error (7). Failed to connect to omega.artoolworks.com port 443: Connection timed out.
E/libar: Error -4 returned from cparamSearch.
E/nftSimpleNative: Unable to automatically determine camera parameters. Using default.
```

Is there is any other way to get calibration file for different device , because using default calibration file causes problem when I change the resolution of the device.
P.S. - Turning off internet is not an option, I need calibration file specific to each device.

Answer (score 3):

The calibration service previously provided by DAQRI is offline as of October 2017. A new project named artoolkitX is now providing a calibration service which can be used by ARToolKit 5. See https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkit5/commit/47e0100441e211cfc4496d5599de0f8fe5531131 and http://www.artoolkitx.org/docs/downloads/

Comment: Thanks It saved lots of time